# BrokenCimSession when stopping a scheduled task

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, wmi

When running the following on one of our Windows machine

```
$name = "My task"
Stop-ScheduledTask -TaskName $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

I get this error:

```
Stop-ScheduledTask : Cannot connect to CIM server. The system cannot find the file specified.
+     Stop-ScheduledTask -TaskName $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (PS_ScheduledTask:String) [Stop-ScheduledTask], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CimJob_BrokenCimSession,Stop-ScheduledTask
```

It does not look like a permission issus since it would look more like

```
Stop-ScheduledTask : Access is denied.
+     [void](Stop-ScheduledTask -TaskName $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...p_ScheduledTask) [Stop-Schedul
   edTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Stop-ScheduledTask
```

A couple of facts to help:

- I'm not running this remotely
- `Get-ScheduledTask` will throw the same `CimJob_BrokenCimSession` error

Comment: Are you able to get the task? I.e.: `Get-ScheduledTask`?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I get the exact same error for `Get-ScheduledTask`

Comment: Seems to just indicate the task name is wrong. Run `Get-ScheduledTask` by itself and find the actual task name.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I do see the task and I wouldn't get that error for a missing task

Answer (score 0):

1. <strike>Are you an administrator on the system? The error says permission denied</strike> (Misread OP)
2. When troubleshooting, it generally helps if you don't have `-erroraction silentlycontinue` if you actually want to see what's erroring. Obviously, you don't have it in a try/catch block, so you can see the error, but having the option to suppress errors doesn't make sense here.

More suggestions:

1. Are you running this command remotely? If you're running it against many servers, check your server list.
2. What happens if you get all the tasks, e.g. `$tasks = get-scheduledtask`, then reference the one you want with `$tasks | where taskname -like "whatever" | stop-scheduledtask` (or its index number in the array, e.g. `$tasks[5]`).
3. I didn't get any errors when I ran the preceding command against tasks that weren't running, but perhaps it does return an error in some cases if the task isn't in the running state.

Comment: I do not get a permission denied, that is what I would get if it was a permission issue

Comment: Oh, I'm an idiot, I read your second "bad permission" example as the actual problem

Comment: I've updated my answer with more suggestions.